# Let table cell/column change color depending on the changing text in the cell

Tags: javascript, html

Good afternooon,

I am trying to change the color of a cell/column depending on the text in the cells of class stat of a table.

With an arduino I collect data from a few devices and export this data via an xml file to a web page. This works well.

But now I would like to give the cells stat a different color depending on the status of the device.
I've found several examples here on the forum but none of them seem to work.

This is my code:
`

```
        <script>
        function GetArduinoInputs()
        {
            nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    if (this.status == 200) {
                        if (this.responseXML != null) {
                            // extract XML data from XML file
                var count;
                // get status
                var num_an = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('stat').length;
                for (count = 0; count < num_an; count++) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("stat")[count].innerHTML =
                        this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('stat')[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                }
                // get temperatuur
                var num_an = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('temp').length;
                for (count = 0; count < num_an; count++) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("temp")[count].innerHTML =
                        this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('temp')[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                }
                // get tijd
                var num_an = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('tijd').length;
                for (count = 0; count < num_an; count++) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("tijd")[count].innerHTML =
                        this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('tijd')[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                }
                // get eenheid
                var num_an = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('eenheid').length;
                for (count = 0; count < num_an; count++) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("eenheid")[count].innerHTML =
                        this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('eenheid')[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            request.open("GET", "ajax_inputs" + nocache, true);
            request.send(null);
            setTimeout('GetArduinoInputs()', 1000);
        }
    </script>
```

```
    <body onload="GetArduinoInputs()" style="background-color:#FEF7A2;">

    <h1 style="font-size:55px;">Monitor</h1>

        <table id="table_id">
     <tr>
           <th>Div 1</th>
           <th>Div 2</th>
           <th>Div 3</th>
           <th>Div 4</th>
           <th>Div 5</th>
           <th>Div 6</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="stat">...</td>
       <td><span class="stat">...</span></td>
           <td><span class="stat">...</span></td>
           <td><span class="stat">...</span></td>
       <td><span class="stat">...</span></td>
           <td><span class="stat">...</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="temp">...</span>&#176;C</td>
        <td><span class="temp">...</span>&#176;C</td>
        <td><span class="temp">...</span>&#176;C</td>
            <td><span class="temp">...</span>&#176;C</td>
            <td><span class="temp">...</span>&#176;C</td>
            <td><span class="temp">...</span>&#176;C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="tijd">...</span><span class="eenheid">...</span></td>
        <td><span class="tijd">...</span><span class="eenheid">...</span></td>
        <td><span class="tijd">...</span><span class="eenheid">...</span></td>
            <td><span class="tijd">...</span><span class="eenheid">...</span></td>
            <td><span class="tijd">...</span><span class="eenheid">...</span></td>
            <td><span class="tijd">...</span><span class="eenheid">...</span></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

`

only with this did I get the cells discolored when I opened the page on the PC and filled in the different texts at the place of the dots. but this no longer worked when the data came from the xml.
`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#table_id td.stat').each(function(){
            if ($(this).text() == 'Klaar') {
                $(this).css('background-color','#32CD32');
            } else if ($(this).text() == 'Aan') {
                $(this).css('background-color','#FED129');
            } else if ($(this).text() == 'Uit') {
                $(this).css('background-color','#FEAD29');
            } else if ($(this).text() == 'ERROR') {
                $(this).css('background-color','#FF4500');
            } 
        });
    });
```

`
Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: Please add more details and clarity and provide your debugging details as [repro]. As a side note: Your code looks completely repetitive to me. A simple for-loop would cut it down by at least 80%.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than letting the color depend on the text inside an element (which may be language-dependent in a multi-language system), I suggest to let both text and color depend on a (language-independent) code and express this dependency through CSS.

CSS will automatically update both text and color whenever the code changes.

```css
html[lang|=nl] span.stat[code='0']::after { content: "Klaar"; background-color: #32CD32; }
html[lang|=nl] span.stat[code='1']::after { content: "Aan"; background-color: #FED129; }
html[lang|=nl] span.stat[code='2']::after { content: "Uit"; background-color: #FEAD29; }
html[lang|=nl] span.stat[code='3']::after { content: "ERROR"; background-color: #FF4500; }
```

```html
<html lang="nl">
  <span class="stat" code="0"></span>
  <button onclick="this.previousElementSibling.setAttribute('code',3)">Turn off</button><br>
  <span class="stat" code="1"></span><br>
  <span class="stat" code="2"></span><br>
  <span class="stat" code="3"></span>
</html>
```